# BRAS server recommendation

Tags: cisco

I am strugling to make an informed decision about a new BRAS server. Currently we have ZTE zxuas10600. The rest of the network is all Cisco, so I was tasked with finding a suitable repacement for it. I am strugling to find any relevant information about the ZTE.

My question is will Cisco 7300, 7600 or 1000 series do BRAS and in what configuration.

Comment: This *sounds* like a shopping question - if it is, this question will probably be closed soon. You could edit it to include a specific question about a feature that you're unsure about, perhaps. I can't give you more guidance, because this question is absolute Greek to me.

Comment: Yes we are going to buy a router in the end, however there is very little info on the subject of making the right choice.

Comment: What is BRAS? If you're using acronyms, please explain them.

Comment: Broadband Remote Access Server. It is a single point of control for managing customer DLS boxes

Comment: You should really include your requirements, and how you think a given piece or line of equipment may or may not fit them - if you want to ask an answerable (and appropriate-for-this-site)  question..

Answer (score 1):

1.) The 7300 series was discontinued a long time ago.

2.) The right box between the ASR1K, 7600 and ASR5K and ASR9K (each an option, but not an exhaustive list) is going to be determined by the features and scale required.  Are you trying to terminate 100 sessions or 100,000?  Are you trying to do large scale NAT or similar?  Scale-out requirements?  Any crypto in the mix?  Protocols in use?

This is usually a much larger question around the types of products and services you're selling.  I'd suggest rephrasing to address your requirements more specifically.